# Shell scripting: cat vs echo for output

Tags: bash

I've written a small script in bash that parses either the provided files or stdin if no file is given to produce some output.  What is the best way to redirect the parsed output to stdout (at the end of the script the result is stored in a variable).  Should I use `cat` or `echo`, or is there another preferred method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `printf` command:

```
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

`echo` is ok for simple cases, but it can behave oddly for certain arguments.  For example, `echo` has a `-n` option that tells it not to print a newline.  If `$var` happens to be `-n`, then

```
echo "$var"
```

won't print anything.  And there are a number of different versions of `echo` (either built into various shells or as `/bin/echo`) with subtly different behaviors.

Answer (score 4):

echo. You have your parsed data in a variable, so just `echo "$var"` should be fine. cat is used to print the contents of files, which isn't what you want here.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` is a fine way to do it. You will have to jump through a few hoops if you want `cat` to work.